# Add items to Properties.Settings at runtime in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration-files

I want to add an item at runtime to my global settings on an ASP.Net web application.  It seems that the `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` object is read-only, or at least it's Attributes are so I was trying to write directly into the `web.config` file. This works correctly but the stuff I found was just dropping my info into the AppSettings section, when I need it to be in the `ApplicationName.Properties.Settings` so it is made available through the Default.Properties object.

The code I have basically goes like this:

```
   Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
   config.AppSettings.Add(mySettingName, myValue);
   config.Save();
```

Which is fine and dandy, except that - obviously enough - my setting turns up in the `<appSettings>` section of the file.

Is there a way I can use the Configuration object to access the ApplicationSettings/ApplicationName.Properties.Settings part of the configuration file? If so how? If not is there another way to write values into my application settings from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` method to retrieve any section from a configuration file. However, there is no support for updating within the framework.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx).